# implementation of custom validation on click of Save & Submit Button in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs and I need to develop single page application. I have a requirement of implementation of angular validation.

I have 10 fields(input, select and listbox) on page and 2 buttons(Save and Submit). When i click on save then 6 fields(just for example) should have valid values and when i click on Submit button- 8 fields should be checked.

But problem is. if i used form tag on page then how to implement these validation.

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

write this code in a controller

```
obj.hasErrorWithsubmit = function (form, field, validation) {
    if (validation) {
        return ($scope.submitted && form[field].$error[validation]);
    }
    return (form[field].$dirty && form[field].$invalid) || ($scope.submitted && form[field].$invalid);
};


    obj.hasErrorWithsave = function (form, field, validation) {
    if (validation) {
        return ($scope.save && form[field].$error[validation]);
    }
    return (form[field].$dirty && form[field].$invalid) || ($scope.submitted ``&& form[field].$invalid); };
```

Write this in html

```
 ng-class="{'classname':obj.hasErrorWithsubmit(Formname,'fieldname','validationType')}">
```

i.e

```
ng-class="{'classname':obj.hasErrorWithsubmit(myform,'textfield1','required')}">

ng-class="{'classname':obj.hasErrorWithsave (myform,'textfield2','required')}">
```

classname is a css class which makes the border red

By clicking  on submit button make $scope.submitted =true
By clicking  on save button make $scope.save =true

Comment: Thanks for your help... I will try to use this solution.